# Percentage from negative target

Tags: percentage

I have these set of targets and actuals:

Actual: "-20" / Target: "-10"

Actual" "50" / Target: "-5"

Actual: "-10" / target: "30"

Target values are anticipated values for each of the 3 categories and actual values are year to date actual values.

- On the first category; in was anticipated that there would be -10 sales compared to the previous period. It turned out to be -20 at the end of the current period. The answer could be -100% or -200%. None of these percentages make sense since percentage completed shouldn't be a negative amount. Another reason that makes the percentages unreasonable is that I cannot perceive the difference between 100% and -100% in this case.
- On the 2nd category, it was anticipated that there would be 5 less sales in the current period but turns out there was actually 50 sales in the current period. The answer should be +1100% if we agree that every amount of 5 is a 100%.
- EDIT: Same as above, the answer for the third category should be -133%

I want to see how much of the target is fulfilled. If actual=target then the answer is 100% although this doesn't make sense if both the actual and the target are negative amount.

If I use (actual/target)*100 negative amounts are always wrong. I need a general formula to calculate the correct answer. I don't mind if the formula has many conditional definitions. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you want something like `-50` and `50` to produce?

Comment: As mentioned above, this question would benefit from more description/details.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information in the original question. I was in hurry to go somewhere. I have added additional information.

Comment: Sorry, I had 2 days off work and didn't get to work on this. Thank you, this website is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When involving negative amount, you should always know what it is that you are looking for.

**example 1:**

if you use the absolute value, you should agree that **target=10** and **actual=-5** is and should be **50%**. however, the 'pure' mathematical way to look at it is **-50%**.

A logical explanation for this is that actual=0 is, as logic predicts, 0%, -5 is even worse! since not only no progress was made, but rather a regression occurred, hence -50% is an understandable result.

**example 2:**

When both are negative then for **target=-10** and **actual=-20**, since anchoring point is **0**, the 'pure' mathematical result is **200%** - and is correct (depending on your point of view of course) since you wanted a decrease of 10 and got a decrease of 20.

*Note:if you want to define your wanted output differently, do so and we will try and come up with a 'custom' percentage calculation method.*

**Edit:**

What you could try in your case (Although I must say I don't agree with this approach):

- **if target>0 and actual > 0**  : (the usual) :

  `(actual/target)*100`
- **if target < 0 and actual < 0**  : (the usual negative) :

  - if (target>actual) - actual is worse than expected :

    `-(actual/target)*100`
  - if (target < actual) - actual is better than expected :

    `(actual/target)*100`
- **if target>0 and actual < 0** :

  `((actual-target)/target)*100`

  corresponds with target=50 , actual = -100 -> **result = -300%**
- **if target<0 and actual > 0** :

  `(abs(target)+actual)/abs(target))*100`

  so that for target = -50 , but actual = 100 -> **result = 300%**

I believe that covers your options and suits your needs.

**Edit:**

A good approach to your issue from my point of view is to look at **absolute values** (rather than **differential values**):

Lets say your sales in month A is 200, and you want a 10% increase in month A+1 -> set your target at 220 and then compare the actual to it, you can also compare it month's A actual and overall a report would use the absolute values for comparison, those are always positive, and can be understood more clearly.

now this:

> target = -10% , actual +5% **and base value of last month 100**

will simply be this:

> target = 90 actual =105 => Overall performance of 105/90 , or (105/90)-1 higher than expected.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information in the original question. I was in hurry to go somewhere. I have added additional information.

Comment: If target=10 and the actual=-5, shouldn't the answer be -150%? I see your logic but even if I agree with 50% how can this answer be put in a formula?

Comment: Thank you Rob. I was thinking about all-positive answers since percentage fulfilled sounds like it should be always positive somewhere between 0 and 100.

Comment: It's Ron :) , I don't understand, did this resolve your issue? all-positive answers don't comply with using negative numbers, as you can see in your edit, you've also noted when negative result is wanted. Edit: 0-100 range is also not bound to reality :)

Comment: Thank you Ron. I used your method on my data and I got what I was thinking about at first place. My only comment is on the last one. I think it should be like this: (abs(target)+actual)/abs(target))*100

Comment: But let's talk about logical sense to all of these. If neither the 0-100 method or this method make logical sense, how else should I approach this problem? is there any other method you can think of? Who knew such a small problem could be this difficult to solve.

Comment: I've corrected the error, thank you. Also, I've added my idea of how you should solve your problem.

Comment: One more thing I just noticed: In the usual negative, based on your conditions, the results for actual=-15/target=-10 would be -150%. This answer seems wrong, doesn't it? -50% is more like it.

Comment: It is a mirror image of target = 10 and actual = 15, resulting in 150%, since 10 is the 100% anchor (or in our case -10 is the 100% anchor).

Comment: I understand it in the positive sense but if -15 would be -150% then what would be -100% or -50%. If both target and actual were -10, then the answer would be +100%, right?

Comment: On your approach: I calculate my sales rate monthly, in each category. Since my product is membership, I could lose some sales in a month. That is why I have negative numbers in my predictions. It's not about selling less, it's about losing the current sales.

Comment: You have a current number of memberships count, this number is absolute and non negative. although you've 'lost' memberships, you will always have 0 or more members, use that number, as you can see using your initial approach is very problematic and obscure.

Comment: - Regarding the usual negative: If we put a +1 at the end of the formula, it makes more sense in my opinion. - Regarding approach: seems like the suggested approach is cumulative. I will look more into it and discuss it with my colleagues to see if it's possible to change our approach.

Comment: Ron, please respond to the "+1" part. Does it make sense to you if we use this >> -(actual/target)+1

Comment: I just realized that +2 makes more sense.

Comment: both +1 and +2 doesn't make sense, although for some specific cases it can make sense (depending on your definition): +1 will make anchor point = target , so when you get actual=target in that case it will be 0%, and +2 will solve that problem but will make actual=-200, target=-100 => result=0%. Providing a 100% bullet proof solution is problematic, you can either continue developing the formula from here, adjusting it to your needs, or (recommended) use the different approach I have suggested.

Comment: Thank you Ron. I think I'm going to have to change my method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat Actual “-50” / Target “50” as 100% fulfilled, you should use the [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) function in your formula.

```
| ((actual / target) * 100) |
```

How you use it in your code depends on the language. In JavaScript, your formula would be like this:

```js
Math.abs((actual / target) * 100)
```

If this is not how you want your scoring to work, please provide an example of what the score should be when the `target` or `actual` is negative.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information in the original question. I was in hurry to go somewhere. I have added additional information.

Comment: I think if actual is -50 and target is 50 then the answer would be -150%

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit with more details about what you want, here is some JavaScript that implements that formula:

```js
function percent_difference(target, actual) {
    if (target === 0 || actual === 0) {
        if (actual > target) {
            return 100;
        } else if (actual < target) {
            return -100;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    var relative_to = Math.min(Math.abs(actual), Math.abs(target));
    var distance_from_target_to_actual = actual - target;
    var fraction_difference = distance_from_target_to_actual / relative_to;
    return 100 * fraction_difference;
}
```

I tried to avoid unnecessary `if` statements to keep the code simple.

The function passes these tests:

```js
function test_percent_difference() {
    console.log("percent_difference(-10, -20)", percent_difference(-10, -20), "should be", -100);
    console.log("percent_difference(-5, 50)", percent_difference(-5, 50), "should be", 1100);
    console.log("percent_difference(30, -10)", percent_difference(30, -10), "should be", -400);
    console.log("percent_difference(15, 0)", percent_difference(15, 0), "should be", 100);
    console.log("percent_difference(0, 0)", percent_difference(0, 0), "should be", 0);
}
```

You can run it for yourself in your browser in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/xXjBU/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with R. 
Assume your data is sample with Target and Actual columns:

```
sample<-structure(list(Actual = c(-20L, 50L, -10L), Target = c(-10L, 
-5L, 30L)), .Names = c("Actual", "Target"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

sample<-
  Actual Target
1    -20    -10
2     50     -5
3    -10     30

#first I compute the percentage deviation as ((Actual-Target)/Actual)*100
#then I will use following two conditions:
# if Actual<0 and Target>0 multiply by -1
#if Actual<0 and Target<0  and if  absolute(Actual)>absolute(Target) multiply by -1 else leave as original percent

sample$diff<-with(sample,((Actual-Target)/Actual)*100)
> sample
  Actual Target diff
1    -20    -10   50
2     50     -5  110
3    -10     30  400

sample$percent<-with(sample,ifelse((Actual<0 & Target>0),diff*(-1),ifelse((Actual<0 & Target<0),ifelse((abs(Actual)>abs(Target)),diff*-1,diff),diff)))

> sample
  Actual Target diff percent
1    -20    -10   50     -50
2     50     -5  110     110
3    -10     30  400    -400

#delete diff column 

sample$diff<-NULL 

#your final output

> sample
  Actual Target percent
1    -20    -10     -50
2     50     -5     110
3    -10     30    -400
```

**Updated:**

To match your answers:

```
sample$diff<-with(sample,((Actual-Target)/Target)*100)
sample$percent<-with(sample,ifelse((Actual<0 & Target>0),diff,ifelse((Actual<0 & Target<0),ifelse((abs(Actual)>abs(Target)),diff*(-1),diff),diff*(-1))))
> sample
  Actual Target       diff   percent
1    -20    -10   100.0000 -100.0000
2     50     -5 -1100.0000 1100.0000
3    -10     30  -133.3333 -133.3333
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used your method on my data but the final answers don't seem to make sense. Take the first one for example. if actual is -20 and target is -10. Actual is a 100% percent worse than the target and should be -100% I suppose.

Comment: In my answer, I am computing percentage difference using actual as the base. So, in case 1, actual is poor performer than target and if you compute percentage change , that will be ((-20-(-10))*100)/(-20)=50% and since actual is performing poor I assigned it as - and hence -50%. You need to make sure which should be the base.

Comment: You are right about the third category. Edited the original post.

Comment: I will shortly update the answer to reflect your updated question.

Comment: thanks for the updates. just a question: in the first category (both negative) what percentage this formula will give me if both numbers are -10. seems it would be 0% but the actual percentage is 100%. right?

Comment: @ Siavash: It will be 0 percentage not the 100%. (100*(-10-(10)))/(-10)=0. Please don't forget to accept the answer if you are okay with.